# Use JMockit to test the concrete methods of an abstract class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jmockit

I have an abstract base class that defines both concrete and abstract methods. I'm wondering if there's a way, using JMockit, to mock this type such that I can declare expectations for the abstract methods and test the implementation of the concrete methods.

Clearly I can do this without using any mocking framework simply be defining a subclass of the abstract one in my test.  Then I can override the abstract methods to return whatever I need.  I'm just wondering if there's a slicker, black-magic JMockit way to do this.

Comment: I thought of using a `MockUp` but it only works with interfaces... The easiest would probably be to create a basic implementation that just returns 0 / false / null / does nothing for all abstract methods.

Comment: `MockUp` can be used to mock any class. What you cannot do is have a `@Mock` method for what is an `abstract` method in the mocked class.

Answer (score 3):

Use `@Mocked` on the abstract class and record/verify expectations on its abstract methods. If you want to execute the non-abstract methods in the mocked class, then apply partial mocking by passing the mocked instance created by JMockit to the `Expectations(Object...)` or `NonStrictExpectations(Object...)` constructor.

Comment: This does not work for me. In 1.39 I use Expectiations(instance) where instance is a @Mocked field. An instance.someMethod call after the Expectations block cause NPE. If I only write Expectation(), then the base class methods are all mocked, it is not a partial mock - as expected.